# What is the highest compression ratio compressor for pdf, djvu, and images

Tags: compression, archive

Comments so far have not been specific with the type of files they needed to compress and didn't reach a definitive answer

I have a 1 TB hard drive full of pdf,djvu mostly and the rest are images and I need to compress it to the least size possible and I don't care about speed.

I tried kgb  and it doesn't take full benefit of my cpu.

I tried tar.lzr, tar.lzma, and tar.7z.  tar.lzr was the best but it didn't offer as much as I expected.

I also noticed nanozip but I saw many people reporting problems with it even though it had the highest percentage in the benchmarks I saw so does anyone have a previous experience with it?

Comment: You ask for "best for specific extensions", then don't specify exactly what you want to compress... Most image file formats & PDFs are compressed already, there's not much to be gained by re-compressing them in general.

Comment: @Mat Well i know that algorithms behave differently on different extensions as they could degrade or even be useless so i needed to get a hairpin answer .... actually some pdf files with kgb are compressed to half their size while others not so much as it depends on recognizable patterns by the algorithms

Comment: CPU performance won't affect the ratio of lossless compression especially when you don't care about speed.

Comment: @yaegashi I just thought that slower meant more calculations for less output so more CPU performance would mean more speed eventually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7z and lzma are the same compression algorithm, with a different container.  `7z` with solid archive mode enabled should do about as well as `tar.7z`, and provide not as bad random random access to a single file.  (Still bad, though.)

pdf uses gzip internally, which makes it not very compressible.  Same for most image formats (although the choice of entropy coder varies; IIRC JPEG's entropy coder is simpler).

In theory, and I don't know of any implementation of this idea, you could have an archiver that undoes the simple gzip or other entropy coding of pdf, png, jpeg, and various other already-compressed file formats.  Then compress that stream with something good like LZMA.  On extraction, you'd extract data from the LZMA stream, and redo the pdf-internal compression on the parts that needed it.  Your output would be the same pdf/jpg/whatever, but the files would potentially have different checksums/hashes.  (So it would be lossless with respect to the final rendered pixels, but not wrt the file bytes.)

PNG and jpeg optimizers sort of implement this idea for a single file: redo the internal compression with the equivalent of gzip -9 instead of the default.

Your best bet is to try compressing a sample of 1GB or so with various compressors, and see what does well.  1GB should be representative, because that's about as big as is reasonable for a [dictionary size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_coder).

Comment: so There is no definitive answer, well `zpaq` is the best so far